# What is the right way to lock a field for a R reference class within a package?

Tags: r, reference-class

I'm trying to make a factory method for creating my reference class objects. I have one field which MUST be read-only, and so I want to give my package users a way to generate these reference class objects with a guaranteed lock on this field.

My RCs and my factory are both in a package. All of this works fine when I'm working outside of the package but I get the following error when I use the RCs in the package:

> Error in methods:::.lockRefFields(def, ...) :
>       the definition of class "(my ref class name)" in package 'my package name' is locked so fields may not be modified   Calls:
>   test_check ... eval -> build.rc ->  ->

It looks like the error comes from this bit in the package:methods source code

```
if (.classDefIsLocked(def)) 
        stop(gettextf("the definition of class %s in package %s is locked so fields may not be modified",
```

**Important:** When loading my source code, I can lock as normal without problems. The problem lies with my RCs being sourced from a package. It appears that their "classDefIsLocked" (whatever that means).

Here is my code that produces the error:

```
build.rc <- function(read_only_field, read_only_value, ref_class_name) {
  generator <- getRefClass(ref_class_name)

  # don't relock if the read_only_field has already been locked
  if (!(read_only_field %in% generator$lock())) {
    generator$lock(read_only_field)
  }

  return(generator$new(read_only_value))
}
```

And here is how I define my RC within my package:

```
#' @exportClass my.ref.class
setRefClass(
  Class = "my.ref.class",
  ...
)
```

Comment: I think I solved the issue: Create a generator, lock the fields, and export the generator. This seems to have worked. So in my case I exported "generator": `generator <- getRefClass(ref_class_name)` after `generator$lock(read_only_field)`